# Automation of git pull using PHP code and NO exec

Tags: php, git, deployment, pull

**The idea**
We would like to continuously and automatically deploy code to multiple hostings. It seems like this would be done best with a repository and a webhook.

**The problem**
We found a lot examples where people used the `exec` command to pull a repo to a host. We don't want to open up the `exec` settings on all hostings, mostly because of the security risks.

**The question**
Has anyone managed to `git pull` a Repo with PHP and without the use of `exec`?

**The alternative**
...would be to setup a cronjob on every hosting that pulls the repo automatically. Only Problem, you can't trigger the pull by a Webhook and the initial effort of installation is higher (otherwise you could only place a PHP file in the root directory of each hosting).

Comment: There's also `system()`, `shell_exec()`, and `popen()`.

Comment: system() is in the same group of disabled commands but i didn't know popen(), i'll check it out